# Is there an SCSS 'no-op' selector?

Tags: sass

In Sass/SCSS, is there any way to **wrap an existing rule like this**:

```
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

**to produce output like this:**

```
.foo,
.bar .foo {
  color: red;
}
```

?

I know you can use the parent selector to accomplish this:

```
.foo {
  &,
  .bar & {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

but that requires modifying the existing rule. Ideally there'd be something magical like this that you could do at the root:

```
@noop,
.bar {
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

(I've tried `@at-root` but that doesn't work in list selectors, and just an ampersand `&` doesn't work at the root)

Comment: How about doing that using a `@mixin`? Like: `.foo { @include noop('.bar', '.baz') { color: red; } }` that outputs `.foo, .bar .foo, .baz .foo { color: red; }`?

Comment: Hey there! Same comment as below, I'm hoping to not modify the original selector and rules at all :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wrap a class without modifying it, you need to create a mixin which extends from that class.

The mixin I created here allows to pass a list as a parameter in order to put multiple selectors.

```
@mixin wrap($content){
  @if (type-of($content) == string){
    & #{$content} {
      @extend #{$content};
    }
  }@else if (type-of($content) == list){
    @each $class in $content{
      & #{$class} {
        @extend #{$class};
      }
    }
  }
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.wrap-1{
  @include wrap('.red' '.blue');
}

.wrap-2{
  @include wrap('.red');
}
```

Outputs:

```
.red, .wrap-2 .red, .wrap-1 .red {
  color: red;
}

.blue, .wrap-1 .blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: But you will always have the `.bar` hardcoded. It won't be reusable.

Comment: And if you want more than one "wrapper"?

Comment: Then let's pass a list in the second parameter.

Comment: I think the issue is you still need to modify the original selector and rule :-/ I'm hoping to find a method that let's you entirely wrap the rule(s) in question, emitting both the rules themselves as well as a wrapped version..

Comment: Could you edit your question with a more practical example in order to be well understood? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I think now I understood what you were actually asking. I hope this is it.

Comment: Clever! I think your latest update is really really close. For my actual purposes it doesn't end up being .foo but something a lot more complex, but this is the closest I've seen :) Thanks!